# Can I use the Nikon ML-L3 remote to do long exposures with a D5200?

Tags: nikon, long-exposure, remote

Can I use the  Nikon ML-L3 Remote Control to take 10-15 minute exposures with my Nikon D5200? If yes, then must I keep the remote pressed during that entire period, or can I lock it somehow and press it again to stop the exposure?  Need help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, in full manual mode on the D5200 you can use Time mode which is a shutter setting in full Manual mode to do so. You will need to click the button once to open it and again to close the shutter. [The full reference manual](http://cdn-10.nikon-cdn.com/pdf/manuals/dslr/D5200RM_NT(11)01.pdf) even suggests using the ML-L3 specifically (page 60).